# ECHO not working within a "TRUE" if condition

Tags: bash, echo

Being a relative beginner, I can't figure this out.  I have a script that is started via cron.  Within this script is an if/fi where I check to see if a (yearly archive) directory does not exist.  It it does not, I create the directory, and ATTEMPT to echo that to the cron's log file that is created for each run.  The directory is created, but the echo does not appear in the log file.

Here is a snippet of the code in question.

```
035: yyyy=`date +%Y`
036: today=`date +%m/%d/%Y`
037: time=`date +%r` #+%l:%M:%S%P`
038: dayofweek=`date +%A`
039: numDayOfWeek=`date +%u`
040:
041: echo "Run Date/Time: $today $time"
042:
043: WFADIR="/data/ssa1/home1/NEI/GAP-EFT-FLAT/$yyyy"
044: if [ ! -d $WFADIR ] ; then
045:    mkdir /data/ssa1/home1/NEI/GAP-EFT-FLAT/$yyyy
046:    chmod 777 /data/ssa1/home1/NEI/GAP-EFT-FLAT/$yyyy
047:    echo ""
048:    echo "New folder $yyyy created in GAP-EFT-FLAT"
049: fi
050:
051: #display test variables for output
052: echo ""
053: echo "HOSTNAME..........: ${HOSTNAME^^}"
054: echo ""
055:
```

And here is the FULL log file.

```
Run Date/Time: 01/03/2023 08:00:01 AM

HOSTNAME..........: BASYSPROD

EFT contribution file found...
Calling expect script to transmit contribution file...
spawn sftp -P 22 -i privatekey.pem username@domain.com:/inbound/NATIO080_ACH_3
Connected to domain.com.
Changing to: /inbound/NATIO080_ACH_3
sftp> put B06737_CON_20230103
Uploading B06737_CON_20230103 to /inbound/NATIO080_ACH_3/B06737_CON_20230103

B06737_CON_20230103                             0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
B06737_CON_20230103                           100% 2470    70.0KB/s   00:00    
sftp> Returned from contribution expect script...
Archiving sent contribution file...
Sending email confirmation...
Process completed...
EFT 401K file found...
Calling expect script to transmit 401K file...
spawn sftp -P 22 -i privatekey.pem username@domain.com:/inbound/NATIO080_ACH_4
Connected to domain.com.
Changing to: /inbound/NATIO080_ACH_4
sftp> put B06736_401K_20230103
Uploading B06736_401K_20230103 to /inbound/NATIO080_ACH_4/B06736_401K_20230103

B06736_401K_20230103                            0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
B06736_401K_20230103                          100% 7980   216.4KB/s   00:00    
sftp> Returned from 401K expect script...
Archiving sent 401K file...
Sending email confirmation...
```

As you can see, the echo from line 41 is in the log file.  Then, as this was the first run for 2023, the 2023 directory did not yet exist.  It WAS created and the permissions were changed as well, with lines 45 and 46, respectively.

drwxrwxrwx.   2 neiauto staff     61 Jan  3 08:00 2023

So why do lines 47 and 48 appear not to execute, and the next echo in the log file is from line 52, 53 and 54, with the hostname display, surrounded by blank lines?

I was expecting a blank line, and "New folder 2023 created in GAP-EFT-FLAT" to be echoed after the Run date/time (first) line of the log file, and before the host name display.

Comment: Please take a look at [*How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Please edit your question and format the actual code using the `{}` code tag button.

Comment: Hello. Please format your question correctly. It is hard to read in this state.

Comment: The line numbers mean we can't use your code as given to test/reproduce. They're harmful, not helpful.

Comment: And please run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds; there are a bunch of obvious quoting problems.

Comment: Also, `chmod 777` is an _extremely_ bad idea -- you're giving even untrusted accounts like `nobody` (which is used for things like sandboxing unauthenticated incoming network connections) write access to your content. `755` is fine, or even `775`, but a `7` in the third position (with the exception of directories with the `+t` bit) is something that IMHO should be a cause for retraining on first offense, and firing if repeated.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want a log showing execution in more useful detail, use the xtrace bit: `bash -x yourscript`, or add `set -x` inside your script to turn logging on (and `set +x` to turn it back off, should that be necessary).

Comment: Beyond that, without seeing a [mre] that reproduces the problem when run _on its own without changes_, it's impossible to say what happened here. For all we know maybe a prior part of the script runs `exec >logfile` so everything you `echo` to stdout went to that file instead of the screen, while the other logs that were actually written were things directed to stderr.

Comment: Don't put line numbers, just add a comment on the lines you want to talk about. [Why is there no line numbering in code sections?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/995714)

Comment: Do you know for sure that the directory didn't already exist and that the `if` test didn't simply fail? Do the actual  lines 043 and 045 in the real script refer to the same directory? (And why aren't you using the WFADIR variable in all three places?)

Comment: Your line 41 is written to a logfile. Why? Something is executing this code, we are missing the part of the code that is causing the problem. Break down the problem do that part that is causing the problem. Good for your debugging/scripting experience and the resylt is the minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely your directory already existed. Add an `else echo $WFADIR already exists` to your code to have your answer next year :-). My guess would be that the same code was run twice (on the same, or another host if shared disk-space was used).